# How to refresh AWS Lambda permission for API Gateway using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am deploying a REST API Gateway using Terraform. Couple of endpoints are accessing Lambda function to return response. Whenever I deploy api-gw using terraform, the Lambda permission doesn't seem to refresh and I have to manually open the api-gw portal in AWS console and again add that lambda function post which it prompts me to allow invoke action. How can I refresh the permission without having to do these manual steps ? I am using below snippet for api-gw deployment and lambda permissions:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deploy" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.id
  stage_name  = ""
  variables  = {
    deployed_at = timestamp()
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "customers_lambda_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowDemoAPIInvokeProjectGet"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = local.lambda_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.execution_arn}/*/GET/api/customers"

}
```

Comment: Your permissions alow only one specific method and resource `/GET/api/customers`. Nothing else will be permitted. Do you have to be that specific? Usually you would use `*/*/*`.

Comment: @Marcin - It is just for example. I have tried with */*/* as well but no luck. API trigger to lambda have to be manually set everytime even after running terraform script

Comment: Can you try with `source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.execution_arn}/*/*/*"`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `aws_api_gateway_deployment` resource should depend on the `aws_api_gateway_integration` so that the lambda integration is created before deployment.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deploy" {
  ...
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.example1,
    aws_api_gateway_integration.example2
  ]
}
```

or use triggers attribute:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deploy" {
  ...
  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
      aws_api_gateway_resource.example1.id,
      aws_api_gateway_method.example1.id,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.example1.id,
    ]))
}
```